# Aspnet Core Spa Application with Angular 8 is not loading

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, single-page-application, asp-net-core-spa-services

I'm struggling with deploying a aspnet core app with an angular spa inside.

I have this on my startup.cs

```
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "Backoffice/dist";
        });



app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "Backoffice";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                spa.Options.StartupTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600);
            }
        });
```

From all the tuts I've seen online this looks pretty straightforward, but when I go to the root of my app the console gives me this errors:

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a
>   non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is
>   enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

And the page stays blank, even after publish and deployed to production server.

But if I navigate to localhost/backoffice/dist the angular loads

Comment: In angular.json,have you used the output path  `"outputPath": "dist",`refer to https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1995#issuecomment-521896775

Comment: yes, I gave up on aws and elastic beanstalk.a good approach for anyone having issues with this is creating a web api with angular template from microsoft and check their configs.... I'm now using docker with heroku and all is working fine and much easier. The aws publish was modifying my web.config weirdly.